# What could be causing drupal to want to reinstall itself after I clear cache?

Tags: 7, installation

I am trying to update Drupal from 7.17 to 7.18. I uploaded a copy of my site from a test server to my production server. Everything installs fine, I actually see the site working, and I can navigate it. Then, as soon as I perform updates on modules and core, I run database updates, and then the site automatically navigates me back to install.php to reinstall the site from scratch. I have tried to reinstall the site several times from scratch, manually and using Drush.

What is the mechanism that determines to redirect to install.php? How can I determine how and why this is happening?

Even though the install.php page is showing up in the browser, `drush status` shows that the site is up, running, successfully connected to the database with correct theme. According to Drush, everything is working properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That occurs because Drupal can't connect to its database. Ensure you have the *settings.php* file in the *sites/default* folder. The *settings.php* file must be readable by the account used to run the web server; it must contain valid database connection string credentials for that server. Make sure that `$base_url` in that file is either commented out (as it is by default), or it's a valid URL for that domain.

See [`_drupal_bootstrap_database()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_database/7) for the place where the install.php redirect occurs.

Also, make sure you run update.php and clear all the caches, whenever  possible.

Comment: All the files are in the correct place. Remember, I can upload the site and actually use it before I do updates. As soon as update db is finished running, the site redirects back to install.php. In an attempt to make sure my settings.php file was not corrupted, I also deleted the defaults directory and installed a fresh copy from a new d7 download. same issue. In a last ditch effort, I chmod'ed 777 the entire drupal install. nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, after my site (D7.23 on Ubuntu 12.04.3) randomly decided it needed to be installed again, I found out that an archive process had changed the permissions on the `sites/default` directory to `755`.

At first I didn't think it was this because the change in permissions was less restrictive i.e. giving user and group more permissions; but I guess there is a security check somewhere in Drupal that will only accept the `sites/default` if it has the permissions `555` — the thinking being that the folder may have been tampered with. The same also seems to be true for `settings.php` in that my install requires it to be `444`, if not, I get the install UI.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this issue.
See the solution given by bryancasler on the page https://www.drupal.org/node/984112

How to fix this problem

- Go to **xampp\mysql\bin**
- Open **my.ini**
- Change "`max_allowed_packet` from `1m` to `16m`
- Save **my.ini**

Now restart MySql through the XAMPP control panel.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Sai. I have spent hours on this and your solution worked for me.